# How Tornado Python handles drop of client connections

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

Im building a Tornado websocket app to save living time of users inside a sql table...As i can see nothing happen from server-side if client connection drop (javascript client)...id like to know how handle this.

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi. When client drops connection does you have invoked `def on_close(self):` from WebSocketHandler?

Answer (score -1):

There is an on_close method in the tornado websocket handler that will get called when the connection closes:

```
class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def open(self, poll_id):
        print 'new connection'

    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'message received %s' % message

    def on_close(self):
        print 'connection closed'

    def send_message(self, msg):
        self.write_message(msg)
```

Comment: i know that.. but on_close method do not handle lose of network connectivity from client side... if i unplug network cable from my one of my clients websocket connection seems still open.. id like to know how to handle this.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the system will detect a problem with an unused network connection. You need to use the connection occasionally (use WebSocketHandler.ping) to be able to detect failed connections.

Comment: well i though ping was the right way but javascript api does not handle ping pong request so should i send message as "ping" ? im stuck with that